# getting string on my browser output while testing servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I am running the following servlet and I am getting some weird output on my browser.The program is working fine without any errors but for some reason, the output of the line `out.println(Add_To_Queue("abc","xyz","pqr"));` is getting displayed
in the form of java string as shown below the code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE> html");  // HTML 5
            out.println("<html><head>");
            out.println("<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>");
            out.println(Test_Servlet("abc","xyz","pqr"));
            out.println("<head><title>TEST SERVLET API Call</title></head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h3>TEST SERVLET</h3>");

            // Tabulate the request information 
            out.println("</body></html>");
        }   
        finally {
            out.close();  // Always close the output writer
        }
    }

      public static Object Test_Servlet(String FirstString,String Secondstring,String ThirdString) throws IOException {
        String accessKey = "myaccesskey";
        String secretKey = "mysecretkey";
        String uRLCppList = "http://myurl.com";
        String method = "POST";
        java.util.Date currentTime = new java.util.Date();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");

        // Give it to me in GMT time.
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        String dateTimeString = sdf.format(currentTime);

        String signature = generateSignature(method, secretKey, dateTimeString);
        String authorization = accessKey + ":" + signature;
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

        params.put("Content of first String", FirstString);
        params.put("Content of Second String", Secondstring);
        params.put("Content of Third String", ThirdString);

        String[] result = sendHttpRequest(uRLCppList, "POST", params, dateTimeString, authorization);

        return result;
    }
```

Here is the browser output:

```
html [Ljava.lang.String;@430bc84a
TEST SERVLET
```

I am using JDK 8, ApacheTomcat 6, Netbeans 7.4 for deployment. I suspect, the result which is getting returned in the variable `result` defined inside `Test_Servlet` method is not getting displayed properly on the web browser.

**Additional Code for SendHttpRequest method:**

```
public static String[] sendHttpRequest(String requestUrl, String method, Map<String, String> params, String dateTimeString, String authorization) throws IOException {
        List<String> response = new ArrayList<String>();
        StringBuffer requestParams = new StringBuffer();

        if (params != null && params.size() > 0) {
            Iterator<String> paramIterator = params.keySet().iterator();
            while (paramIterator.hasNext()) {
                String key = paramIterator.next();
                String value = params.get(key);
                requestParams.append(URLEncoder.encode(key, "UTF-8"));
                requestParams.append("=").append(URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
                requestParams.append("&");
            }
        }
        URL url = new URL(requestUrl);
        URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("accept", "application/json");
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("datetime", dateTimeString);
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("authorization", authorization);
        urlConn.setUseCaches(false);

        // the request will return a response
        urlConn.setDoInput(true);

        if ("POST".equals(method)) {
            // set request method to POST
            urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
        } else {
            // set request method to GET
            urlConn.setDoOutput(false);
        }

        if ("POST".equals(method) && params != null && params.size() > 0) {
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConn.getOutputStream());
            writer.write(requestParams.toString());
            writer.flush();  
        }

        // reads response, store line by line in an array of Strings
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            response.add(line);
        }
        reader.close();
        return (String[]) response.toArray(new String[0]);
    }
```

Comment: That is what happens when you print an array, yes. What were you expecting to happen? Also, your DOCTYPE is wrong.

Comment: @immibis I was expecting a JSON response

I think for DOCKTYPE you are referring to include `<` and `>` around the `html`, am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Test_Servlet` method is returning an array of `String`. The result of calling `toString()` on an array is the string you're getting which includes the type and the object Id.

Not sure exactly what you're trying to do but you could put the strings out by iterating through the returned array.

Comment: I added additional code for `sendHttpRequest` method where `toString` method is being called `writer.write(requestParams.toString());`, Do you think this could be the problem?

Comment: Servlets won't convert your response to JSON automatically, you'll have to do that by hand. How you're sending the request isn't changing how your response is formatted. A quick a dirty way to check would be to serialize your response to JSON using `GSON`. A better solution would be to look into a tool such as Jersey or RESTEasy. Those tools provide a robust framework and include things like automatic serialization / de-serialization.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have few more questions.1) Do you think that the line `urlConn.setRequestProperty("accept", "application/json");` in my code is accepting the JSON format which can be used to display the JSON response on the browser? 2)If I have to use the dirty approach you suggested, where can I use `GSON` in my code?

Comment: The `Accept` header informs the server of what kind of data format the client will accept. It's up to the server to encode the data in one of those formats. To use `GSON` edit `doGet` to read `out.println(gson.toJson(Test_Servlet("abc","xyz","pqr")));`. You'll have to instantiate the `GSON` object first.

Answer (score 0):

```
html [Ljava.lang.String;@430bc84a
```

`html` comes from the `out.println("<!DOCTYPE> html");` where you need to close the tag.

The `[Ljava.lang.String;@430bc84a` is the default to toString for an array of strings, telling you where the reference exists. The [ - means array and what follows is the type which happens to be java.lang.String. This is JVM level output

Id do something like:

`String resultStr = "";
for(String s: result){
    //format however you wish, this separates each element by a space
    resultStr += s + " ";
}
return resultStr`

If you want to put the results in a table or something, you could return the array and use the same for loop to encapsulate each element in a tag. The choice is yours and either works fine

Comment: I added additional code for `sendHttpRequest` method where `toString` method is being called `writer.write(requestParams.toString());`, Do you think this could be the problem?